# Postman custom authentication

Tags: web-services, symfony, authentication, postman

Is there a way on **Postman** to pre-execute a request B before executing a request A ?

**CONTEXT**: I created a **Symfony** application that manages a set of webservices.
Most of the routes can only be called once the user is fully authenticated (using *form_login* and *firewall* for those who are familiar with the framework)

Therefore, I have to call first:

**POST /login**

- username
- password

before being able to call

**GET /some_secured_route**

(that return a JSON response)

This works fine when I call the routes successively and manually in the **Postman builder**.

---

However, I'm trying to create a collection of test to run in the  **Postman runner**. How can I invoke to call the the **/login** request before testing the a secured route ?

- Is there a way to do so in the *Pre-request script* in the **Postman builder** ?
- *Postman* supports several type of Authorization, (Basic Auth, Digest Auth, OAuth...). Does it support somehow a custome one ?

Any help or link to related post would be much appreciated.
I wish you all a very good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can use a custom authentication mode in Postman. I think what you need is [Jetpacks for Postman](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/16/ridiculously-easy-api-testing-introducing-jetpacks-for-postman/).

> **Chain requests together:** Environment and global variables can be set inside the JS test script. You can extract data from one request and use it inside another request. This allows you to chain multiple requests together.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use postman interceptor as describer here: https://community.getpostman.com/t/interceptor-integration-for-postman-native-apps/5290